# Search-as-you-type on IP datatype in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, ipv4

We are currently adding search-as-you-type in the UI for some fields in our index.

For String-fields the functionality of Elasticsearch allows a number of ways of doing this, e.g. via match_phrase_prefix query on the analyzed tokens or via ngrams during indexing.

However as IPv4-Addresses are [stored as long](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/ip.html) internally, doing wildcard or prefix searching on them is not easily possible as far as I see.

One can use range-queries for searching for IP-Ranges, but I rather would like to let them user enter "118" and display matches for "168.1.118.32" as well as "118.43.119.4" and "1.1.1.118".

Is there a built in way to perform such queries? Or do we need to store the field as analyzed string separately?

Comment: I haven't done this before, have u considered using ElasticSearch Regex?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-regexp-query.html

Comment: @nafas: Thanks, this seems to work, but I am reluctant to use this as we have millions of documents and so I would expect quite a performance hit with regular expressions. For Strings we use prefix-match or phrase-prefix-match to avoid the costly wildcard and regexp match types.

Comment: to be honest if you have static prefix (not having any wild card at the beginning), u won't have that much hit on performance . I haven't used regex in ElasticSearch but used it in Solr, so I expect similar behaviour

Comment: Alternatively mate,if possible maybe you can index it differently. (e.g. an array of integer with size of 4.)

Comment: @cent One solution is to index another field as "ip_searchable" or something, where you analyze and break the IP on the dots, or whatever your use case requires.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I ended up with a multi-field configuration in the index template where the field is written once as IP-Address and a 2nd time as string with a special tokenizer which splits it into the four octets for quick searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more investigation we used a [multi field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) to store the IP address twice, once as normal IP type and a second time as analyzed value where we split the IP into it's 4 octets so we can search on these parts separatedely.

In the template we use the following pattern to split up the value when writing to the index:

```
    "analyzer": {
      "ipv4analyzer": {
        "tokenizer": "ipv4tokenizer"
      }
    },
    "tokenizer": {
      "ipv4tokenizer": {
        "pattern": "([0-9]{1,3})",
        "type": "pattern",
        "group": "1"
      }
    }
```